# What is a more Ruby-like way of doing this command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want do this:

```
sender_email = @request.user.paypal_email if @request.user.paypal_email == "paypal@anonymous.com"
```

So basically I want to only execute the command if the users paypal email is `"paypal@anonymous.com"`. This works fine but it seems like there is room for refactoring.

Comment: There isn't much more you could do here given just what you have in your example. What is the context of this code? A model?

Comment: what do you do with sender_email after that? what happens if the user has a normal email, for example?

Comment: One thought is you might want `paypal@anonymous.com` to be a constant to prevent misspellings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this code is in your controller, then it can definitely be refactored. You typically want logic like this to be in the models since it's easy to write unit tests and it's not the job of the controller to know so much about the user model.

There's a few ways you could refactor this, but I would recommend moving the logic to the user model like so:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def sender_email
    paypal_email if paypal_email == "paypal@anonymous.com"
  end
end
```

Then your controller wouldn't need to know as much and could just do:

```
sender_email = @request.user.sender_email
```

Comment: Your code is not equivalent to the code of OP. Yours will set sender_email to nil if paypal_email != "paypal@anonymous.com", whereas the code of OP will leave it unchanged.

Comment: True, but I'm sure there's more to the picture that could be refactored as well. There's likely more code that's related to this logic. My answer was just an example of why and how you should move model logic to where it belongs.

Answer (score 10):

```
@request.user.paypal_email
```

Some would advocate that you 'use only one dot'. ([See 'Law of Demeter'.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) You might want to consider using [Rails 'delegate' method](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :paypal_email, :to => :user
end
```

Then you can write

```
@request.paypal_email
```

or if you prefer

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  delegate :paypal_email, :to => :user, :prefix => true
end

@request.user_paypal_email
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could rewrite using a block if, but the only difference is future flexibility or "readability". Maybe your question should be "Does rails provide something that does this?". The answer to that question is not that I know of. If your code does what you want I see no reason to change it.