# Ruby (Rails) Delegate attributes to another model's method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, alias, shortcut

-EDIT-

After reading about the Delegate method from the first answer, my question is this, is it possible to delegate two different methods to another single method.

IE: I currently have: @photo.attachment.file.url, and @photo.attachment.height, and @photo.attachment.width

I'd like to be able to access all of these via @photo.file.url, @photo.file.height, @photo.file.width.

The reason for the syntax is Attachment is a model that uses Paperclip to manage files, Paperclip is generating the .file method (the model is called Attachment, the model uses Paperclip's `has_attached_file :file`).

-ORIGINAL QUESTION-

I was wondering about aliasing methods and attributes in Ruby (I think this is a general ruby question, although my application is in Rails 3):

I have two models: Photo has_one Attachment.

Attachment has "height" and "width" attributes, and a "file" method (from Paperclip).

So by default I can access bits of the Attachment model like so:

```
photo.attachment.width # returns width in px
photo.attachment.height # returns height in px
photo.attachment.file # returns file path
photo.attachment.file.url #returns url for the default style variant of the image
photo.attachment.file.url(:style) #returns the url for a given style variant of the image
```

Now, in my photo class I have created this method:

```
def file(*args)
    attachment.file(*args)
end
```

So, now I can simply use:

```
photo.file # returns file path
photo.file.url # returns file url (or variant url if you pass a style symbol)
```

My question is, I was able to direct `photo.attachment.file` to just `photo.file`, but can I also map height and width to `photo.file`, so that, for the sake of consistency, I could access the height and width attributes through `photo.file.height` and `photo.file.width`?

Is such a thing possible, and if so what does it look like?

Comment: Why not just delegate Photo#height to Attachment#height? Why bother with photo.file.height?

Comment: Just for the sake of consistency. Photo.height is fine, but if all file related commands are under Photo.file that's more fitting with Principal of Least Surprise, at least to me. Also, just curious if it can be done.

Comment: Why is this not accepted ? Rails delegate method is the answer here right ? What was the problem with that ?

Comment: Maybe I'm failing to understand something here, but what I want to know is if I can delegate `@photo.attachment.height`, where `height` is an attribute of the attachment model, to `@photo.file.height`, where `file` is a method provided by a plugin. I don't understand how to do that based on the answer given, and I wasn't able to deduce it for myself. So, if you can answer that question, you get the bounty :)

Comment: Regarding your edit, ruby doesn't have a separate notion of attributes compared to methods. They're all just methods.

Comment: re: @photo.attachment.file.url.  Doesn't Paperclip allow you to just call @photo.attachment.url?  If so, then maybe you can avoid referencing the File model altogether and just reference Attachment, which you can use delegate?

Comment: Monocle: it would if I had called the attached file "attachment". I know this is confusing, but because of a migration from an older configuration my setup is: "Photo has_one :attachment" (Attachment is a model) "Attachment has_attached_file :file" Originally it was just "Photo has_attached_file :file", (I called it that because I didn't want to type attachment every time, and Photo.photo sounded weird. ... I know.)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

So what you are asking is that

```
photo.file       --> photo.attachment.file
photo.file.url   --> photo.attachment.file.url
photo.file.width --> photo.attachment.width
```

You can't solve this with delegates, because you want that `file` to mean different things based on what follows next. To achieve this you would need to reopen paperclip, which i would not recommend (because i believe the api is good the way it is).

The only way i can think of to solve this, is to add eliminate the `file` level too. Like so:

```
photo.width      --> photo.attachment.width
photo.file       --> photo.attachment.file
photo.url        --> photo.attachment.file.url
```

This you could then solve by using a `delegate` for each of the wanted methods.

So you write

```
class Photo
  delegate :width, :height, :file, :to => :attachment
  delegate :url,   :to => :'attachment.file'
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "You can't solve this with delegates, because you want that file to mean different things based on what follows next."   There's the answer. Thanks!   I think your way is probably best, though it does involve a little rewriting. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use Rails 'delegate' method. Have a look at my answer for this question:

[What is a more Ruby-like way of doing this command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642105/what-is-a-more-ruby-like-way-of-doing-this-command/4642741#4642741)

Comment: GREAT suggestion! I had never seen "delegate" before! Do you have an example of how I could delegate attachment to `photo.file` specifically, rather than just to `photo` ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that comes to mind is to delegate url method in attachment to file:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :url, :to => :file
end
```

This way you can call photo.attachment.url, photo.attachment.width, photo.attachment.height, which for me seems pretty consistent. You could optionally alias attachment to file - this way you'd get the exact method names you asked for (photo.file.width, photo.file.url), but I would not recommend that, because it seems confusing (calling an attachment "file").

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def file
    attachment
  end
end
```

Comment: Right -- the issue is, I currently have photo.file pointing to photo.attachment.file, what I'd like is to keep that and also point photo.attachment.height and photo.attachment.width to photo.file so that photo.file.height (from photo.attachment.height) and photo.file.url (from photo.attachment.file.url ) would both work.

Answer (score 0):

With plain Ruby you can use [Forwardable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html):

```
require 'forwardable'

class RecordCollection
  attr_accessor :records
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegator :@records, :[], :record_number
end
```